# Searching a range of records in a vector

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iterator, range

I have a vector with 4 objects in them. The object contains a property called staff number. The system prompts the user to give 2 inputs to search the vector.
Input number 1 : starting point (Should give a staff number)
Input number 2: end point(Should give a staff number)

for example if the user gives input number 1 as Ad0 and input number 2 as Ad2.
The system should locate where the object with staff number of Ad0 is in the vector and then start displaying all the values to the screen until its finds the ending point, which is input number 2. So when system finds the object with staff number of Ad2 it should stop iterating.

To achieve this , this is what i have done :-

```
cout<<"Enter Staff number Start Point"<<endl;
cin>>start;
cout<<"Enter Staff number End Point"<<endl;
cin>>end;

if(start.find("Ad")!= std::string::npos && end.find("Ad")!=     std::string::npos) {

    for(Administrator iter: adminTObj.getVectorAdministrator()) {
        if(iter.getStaffNumber()==start) { 
        //checks for the staff number

            while(iter.getStaffNumber()==end) { 
            //if found loop the vector until it meets staff number which ends the range

                cout<<iter.toString2(iter)<<endl; //display the values

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The with this code is it only displays one value. I assure that there are 4 values in the vector which i am iterating through. For example if i give the range as "Ad0" to "Ad3", it only display the record "Ad0" but it doesn't display "Ad2".

What seems to be the problem here ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the condition on the while in first place..

Comment: Also, range-based for loops do not give you an iterator. You might prefer a reference to Administrator rather than making copies: for (Administrator& admin: ...) or alternatively for (auto& admin: ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `while` in the `for` loop in the way you are doing it because the iterator will never get advanced.

I would try something along these lines:

```
auto vector = adminTObj.getVectorAdministrator();
auto first = std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), start);
while(first != vector.cend()) {
    if(*first != end) {
        std::cout << *first << std::endl;
    } else break;
}
```

Like your code, it assumes that the vector is sorted.

Comment: I tried doing that , but it resulted in an infinite loop.

Comment: I missed something. Give me a second.